# Arc Lighter: Relationship between transformer inductance, oscillating frequency and energy of the spark

Tags: transformer, high-frequency, oscillation, arc

I'm building an arc lighter using  YouTube videos as a reference.

[image]

This circuit from GreatScott worked for me.

I'm now trying to understand the relationship between the **transformer inductance and frequency of oscillation** and **spark energy**.

This is what I have noticed so far:

1. The capacitor bank and resistance shown in the circuit are to ensure MOSFET doesn't overheat.
2. Spark gets generated quickly at some frequencies than others.
3. Higher frequency spark burns, doesn't shock.
4. I have also noticed by increasing the Vcc, larger curreny gets drawn and I get stronger arcs that melt the wire insulation.

Is there an equation that can be used to describe the circuit?

Edit: [The YouTube video mentioned in my question.](https://youtu.be/iHkKTGYc6aA?si=hfBkAHcHdBrU0guP)

Comment: 1. More commonly known as a snubber circuit.

Comment: There exists an equation (or system of equations really) that describes (read: exhibits behavior analogous or equivalent to) your circuit, yes.  But you are asking about a partial differential equation, a very advanced topic, and not one that can be solved in general (we normally use simulators to approximate them). Are you sure this is what you want to know?

Comment: @TimWilliams, could you name any simulator that you mention. So far I have been using a sort of trial and error method with this circuit, increasing/decreasing coil turns, adding gap between cores, varying the Vcc, etc. I would love to get some prospective on the underlying theory. Also if I could simulate the whole thing, it would make my trial and error approach much faster.

Comment: LTspice is a common choice, and is free; but notice you will have to model the transformer's inductance and capacitance realistically yourself (no one can provide a stock model of a custom part), for which you should research the lumped-equivalent model of a transformer; and a spark discharge, doesn't have a very well-defined description (it is an impressively nonlinear phenomenon), but for AC purposes, could be modeled as a ballpark value of resistance if nothing else.